# combobox rowsource based on forms record source (distinct) field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form record source set to a elaborate SQL select statement. That is working fine. If it helps to know, the form layout is Tabular. Here is an example of the data:

```
order carrier billto employee
1     smgd    horm   chrnic
2     axxm    sele   chrnic
3     smgd    horm   redned
4     mcta    cron   greand
5     mcta    cron   greand
```

Its basically unbilled order entries. I want a combo box to show distinct employee names (chrnic, redned, greand) based on the current records showing. I will be coding it to filter the form. Seems simple, but I am having trouble

Things I have tried:

- Tried setting rowsource to me.recordsource, but get an

  - It appears that I would need to parse & edit that string
- I copied the complex query & put as combo box record source & that worked to filter the form, so I know that filter logic is correct. I just want it to be dynamic so we only have to change SQL statement in one place if needed

Comment: Please saw your sql statement. or add **Select Distinct employee from table** as combobox rowsource.

Comment: Bear in mind that is example data, keeping with that lets say its: SELECT orders.order, orderdetail.carrier, orderdetail.billto, orderdetail.employee FROM orders o JOIN orderdetail od ON o.order=od.order WHERE orders.billed=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I have a form record source set to a elaborate SQL select statement."*

Save that query as a named `QueryDef`.  I will pretend you chose *qryRecordSource* as the name.

*"I want a combo box to show distinct employee names ... based on the current records"*

For the combo box row source use ...

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT employee
FROM qryRecordSource
ORDER BY 1;
```

And then to filter the form based on the combo selection, add a command button, *cmdApplyFilter*, and use this in its click event procedure ...

```vb
Me.Filter = "[employee] = '" & Me.YourComboName.Value & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

If the employee names can include an apostrophe, use this for the `Filter` expression ...

```vb
Me.Filter = "[employee] = '" & _
    Replace(Me.YourComboName.Value, "'", "''") & "'"
```

If you want to include a combo row to clear the filter, use a `UNION` query as the combo row source ...

```sql
SELECT "*** ALL ***" AS employee
FROM Dual
UNION
SELECT employee
FROM qryRecordSource
ORDER BY 1;
```

... where *Dual* is any table or query which returns just one row.  Then in the command button click event you can do ...

```vb
If Me.YourComboName.Value = "*** ALL ***" Or _
        IsNull(Me.YourComboName.Value) Then
    Me.Filter = vbNullString
    Me.FilterOn = False
Else
    Me.Filter = "[employee] = '" & Me.YourComboName.Value & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End If
```

And actually you wouldn't even need the command button.  You could set the `Filter` from the combo's `AfterUpdate` event.

Comment: @greggmcfg I changed the second query from `UNION ALL` to just `UNION`.  With just `UNION`, the query returns only unique rows, so `DISTINCT` is no longer needed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `QueryDef`, based on the name you provided I assume you just mean a query object. Duh, seems so obvious now. Your last statement is the direction I want to go, but how do I turn off the filter without a command button?

Comment: Right, a `QueryDef` is a query object.  If you use a query like the second example for your combo row source, you can use the combo's `AfterUpdate` event to check whether its selected row = `"*** ALL ***""`.  If it is equal, `FilterOn = False`.  Otherwise, build and apply the filter as in the `Else` block.

Comment: Alright, I get it now, thanks a bunch! BTW I actually used: SELECT TOP 1 "*** ALL ***" AS employee FROM qryRecordSource UNION SELECT DISTINCT employee FROM qryRecordSource ORDER BY 1; // I was a bit confused by the ORDER BY 1, but upon looking it up it just a quickhand for column 1 name; some said its because practice, but it errors if you put ORDER BY employee. So is that some odditiy of ACCESS jet/tsql or whatever?

Comment: `ORDER BY <column ordinal number>` is not limited to Access.  I'm sure I've used it with other databases in the past but I don't remember which.  It's especially convenient when you want to order by a calculated field expression in the `SELECT` clause but avoid re-typing that field expression in the `ORDER BY`.  BTW, you shouldn't need to use `DISTINCT` in the query you're using.  But it doesn't hurt, either.  :-)